# Jenkins SonarQube link not clickable

Tags: ios, swift, jenkins, sonarqube

I have setup jenkins and it is working fine. Now after referring to all given links I am setting up SonarQube for jenkins.

https://riis.com/blog/sonarqube-jenkins-swift-integration/

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Get+Started+in+Two+Minutes

Now I can see sonarqube option in jenkins left side menu of job but it is not clickable. Can you help me if I am missing anything?
[image: reference image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was so tricky. It was because SonarQube was failing. On first success link got enabled (clickable).